# Query the storage occupied by a user. [ORACLE]

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

How can I make a query that shows the space occupied by a user, grouping by devices and files?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions like "how to do this?" without showing any attempt are not usually welcome here.

Comment: @Aleksej I have queried the table "dba_segments". But it does not show the information I need.

Comment: Why the plsql tag if you ask for a query? I removed that tag but you added it again, is there a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
select f.file_name
     , f.tablespace_name
     , s.owner
     , sum( s.bytes/ (1024*1024*1024)) GB
from dba_data_files f
   , dba_segments s
where f.tablespace_name = s.tablespace_name
group by f.file_name
       , f.tablespace_name
       , s.owner
```